# Where is the mapping for "Find Source" stored in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, pdb-files

When the user browses to the source location (because PDBs are from a non-local build), where is that mapping stored?

If it's in the .suo, is there any way to programmatically add a mapping? (as the sln is generated in this case any way)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a better idea to just look into what they call "Source Server", which is something of a misnomer as it actually just adds information about how to get sources from your VCS to the PDB files. You could look at the MSDN magazine article [Source Server Helps You Kill Bugs Dead In Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163563.aspx), or you could just look up SrcSrv in the index for the [Debugging Tools For Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) help.

According to the magazine article, you also need to install Perl on the build box (the author of the article apparantly built it himself!), but thankfully it is supposed to work out-of-the-box with Subversion, CVS, or even Perforce -- not just Visual Source Safe -- so there's a good chance you wouldn't have to write any Perl yourself. (Not to dis Perl, but I'm guessing you don't know it very well or at all -- I'm a *nix lover, and I'm not exactly fluent myself.) And even if you use some VCS that isn't supported out-of-the-box, it's quite possible someone else has already written the needed Perl and posted it on their blog.